# Android 4.x VerifyError caused by Kotlin method

Tags: android, kotlin

Recently I've started to play with Kotlin language and I try to run a very simple app. I have two files: MainActivity.kt and VersionSupport.kt with a few kotlin methods.

I don't have any problems with the app on Nexus 5 (a real device and emulator) with Android 5.x and 6.0. Problems begin when I try to run the app on 4.x versions of the OS.

In my MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    textView.apply { text = "Hello kotlin!" }

    supportsKitKat { longToast("kitKat") }
}
```

And here is the support methods implementation

```
public fun supportsKitKat(code: () -> Unit) {
    supportsVersion(code, Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
}

private fun supportsVersion(code: () -> Unit, sdk: Int) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= sdk) {
        code.invoke();
}
```

I use android studio 2.0 preview 3b and kotlin 1.0.0-beta-4583

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.VerifyError: pl/kpob/bootstrap/utils/VersionSupportKt
     at pl.kpob.bootstrap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:21)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin beta 4 is incompatible with Android Studio's Instant Run feature. You need to turn off Instant Run. The incompatibility will be resolved in the next update of Kotlin.